# How to temporary elevate aplication to administrator in standard level account (windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, administrator, uac

How to temporary elevate aplication to administrator in standard level account (windows 7)?

If you know Linux we can elevate program into Root level, how to that in Windows 7 ?
I have "standard" level account but i want to temporary elevate program to have ability access all Windows location.

I cant do that ---when using "Run as Administrator" --- when i click that the Program will use setting and save its configuration in "Administrator" (C:\User\Administrator) directory but not in "my account" (C:\User\My Account)

Is it possible or this feature only available in Mac n Linux?

Comment: If using "run as Administrator" changes the behavior of the application and where it looks for data files, then the application has implemented its data files the incorrect way, and it should be reported to the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

When you right-click, Run as Administrator, it starts that application in a separate environment and shows you the program, but things like network mappings are not carried over. This is a security measure which was implemented due to how easy it was to hack in Windows XP.

It is possible to bridge this gap, but to tell you what to do, would require us to have more information as to what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: True.... 
"When you right-click, Run as Administrator, it starts that application in a separate environment and shows you the program"
Its only show the Program GUI but run on different environtment.
So there is no solution then.. well ..
It sucks because some Games and Important Apps need Administrator level but i use "standard" account to avoid virus and junk.

Comment: You can force an app to start as administrator, and enter that password each time, or additionally grant the rights to a specific folder which sometimes solves the issue and it no longer needs to be run as administrator.

Comment: Yes i can force it but the Program not run in "my account" folder but in "Administrator" (C:\user\Administrator)

Comment: Indeed. Does means it keeps its settings there too, shielded away. You possibly can transfer the settings to the administrator account's required folder and continue from there, but only if you know what you're doing